# What did James Gosling mean when told that C# is Java with no reliability, productivity and security?

Tags: java, c#, .net, jvm

Gosling said that "[C# is] sort of Java with reliability, productivity and security deleted." (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)))

Comment: He means "I think we should start a flame war discussing which language is best"

Comment: @Matthew but what if one indeed is better than another, isn't it important to know ?

Comment: Also, linked from the exact same wikipedia article you referenced: http://www.cnet.com/news/why-microsofts-c-isnt/

Comment: @Matthew disagree 200%. He means [Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6418/31260)

Comment: @RS Whatever he meant he said it in January 2002. That's before the C# version 1.0 specification was written. If you had any idea how much has changed since you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Though the question as stated evokes opinion and interpretation, perhaps even exegesis, it does go to some programming principles that are on topic here and merit discussion (e.g. type safety, program soundness).

Comment: And now we use sun.misc.Unsafe for things like this. Soon to be in a good way part of spec. So James Gosling is great but not always right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# incorporates "unsafe" capabilities that allow pointer manipulation.  C#'s underlying platform, CLR/CLI (.NET bytecode), was intended to be somewhat more language agnostic than Java (and Java's byte-code).  .NET supported, for example, what was called Managed C++ (I have the T-shirt!), though that never really caught on.  Managed C++ supported managed as well as unmanaged objects.

C#'s unsafe capabilities allow pointer manipulation, and so, reduce reliability and security as they these extensions are not type safe.

However, the unsafe capabilities are extremely useful.  For example, you can memory map files and access the file mapped content without constantly copying bits of the mapped file into some other type-safe object (avoiding both the copy and the generation of soon-to-be garbage).

Further, the "unsafe" features are nicely contained.  For one, you can declare whether your program wants to allow any unsafe features at all.  For another, if you choose to allow them, then you can clearly locate where any unsafe features are being used (via the keyword `unsafe`)!

(Note: new language Rust also has a similarly well-contained unsafe capability.)

Still, undisciplined use of unsafe can land you in the same territory as C or (true) C++, with crashes much delayed after some buggy code sequence.  I think that Gosling was saying that if you allow unsafe code, then the whole program is suspect, maybe even the whole language: and he's not incorrect from a logical point of view.

However, I think that history is showing that "unsafe" capabilities are not the big safety problem it was presumed to be: that unsafe can be avoided, or, judiciously used-to-advantage, just like invoking native code/APIs (which Java and C# both allow).

I'm guessing that the productivity part of the argument comes from the delayed bugs that happen when unsafe is allowed.

Comment: "For example, you can memory map files . . ."  Not the best example, since you can also do that in Java since version 1.4 (2002).

Comment: @Kevin, the whole quote is "you can memory map files and access the file mapped content without constantly copying bits of the mapped file into some other type-safe object (avoiding both the copy and the generation of soon-to-be garbage)".  Are you saying this fully the case?  (Sure we can memory map files in Java, but in C# you can ***directly*** access that memory, i.e. no "read" method invocation is required, just pointer access.)

Comment: Yes, if I understand what you mean.  You can read the raw bytes of a memory mapped file as primitive bytes.  More practically, a type-safe object can encapsulate its use of a memory mapped file instead of holding all that data on the Java heap.

Comment: @Kevin, using a "read" call to get those bytes into a type-safe object?  That's not the same.  In C# you don't need to do a "read" call to get the bytes at all as you have direct access if you want to use unsafe, though again, you don't have to use unsafe if you don't want, and can still access memory mapped files by copying data portions into byte arrays or some such (i.e. a "read" call) .

Comment: Or a primitive.  Are you saying C# can do something useful with a memory mapped file without reading or writing any heap or stack variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "access" if not reading and writing.

Comment: @Kevin, C# has unsafe pointers.  You don't need to make a call of any sort to access a memory mapped file (which obviously is outside the garbage collected heap).  Above and beyond the direct access via pointers, it also has the same as Java, which is to say if you want to access the memory mapped content, you can make a call to read a single byte, or a call to read several bytes into a byte array.  However, C#'s unsafe features are like C/C++ in that you can simply dereference and/or subscript a pointer without the need for a library call and that is what I mean by direct access.

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Kevin, you are most welcome, and thanks for the discussion.

Comment: I think Gosling would have agreed that 1 line of unsafe code in a 100,000 line program was a 100,000 line unsafe program, and, I would have to agree with that (from a theoretical, proof point of view).  Thus, the conclusion that C# is wholly unsafe (with which I don't agree).  However, I think the same is ultimately true for native method invocation (it is not inherently safe), which both Java (JNI) and C# have, and, have more or less proven to be usable without destroying the integrity of the whole programming language.

Comment: I miss some things in your answer. First, Gosling had IMHO only one intent - he clearly wanted to badmouth a competitor.  Moreover, .NET **supports** (not supported) what was formerly called Managed C++ and now is called C++/CLI. It very much alive, because is the most important bridging technology between native and managed code in the .NET world.

Comment: @Doc, (1) I agree, though he had a point he was trying to make and I try to respect that.  And (2) wow, who knew?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI  Thanks for pointing that out.  I did not realize they had made another effort in that direction, and that it was still supported today, and that it is popular!  I'm going to wear my Managed C++ t-shirt today!